# If $80\%$ order coffee, $25\%$ order biscotti and coffee, what is the probability someone does not order biscotti given they do not order coffee?

Tags: probability

Really have no idea how to answer this question. Any help would be appreciated!

In an Italian breakfast cafe, a waitress has observed that $80\%$ of her customers order coffee and $25\%$ order both biscotti and coffee.

What is the probability that a randomly selected customer would not order a biscotti, given that he or she does not order coffee?

You need to know the percentage of her customers that order biscotti to answer the above question - let's assume that it is $40\%$.

Comment: classic problem on Baye's

Answer (score 1):

$Pr(B^c|C^c) = \frac{Pr(B^c\cap C^c)}{Pr(C^c)}=\frac{1-Pr(B\cup C)}{1-Pr(C)}=\frac{1-(Pr(B)+Pr(C)-Pr(B\cap C))}{1-Pr(C)}$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the event "does not order biscotti" and $B$ the event "does not order coffee." We want $\Pr(A|B)$, which is $\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

We need to find the two probabilities on the right. Calculation of $\Pr(B)$ is easy. It remains to calculate $\Pr(A\cap B)$, the probability of ordering neither biscotti nor coffee.

To find $\Pr(A\cap B)$, note that the probability of ordering coffee **or** biscotti, or both, is $0.8+0.4-0.25$. This can be done by "formula," or by drawing  a Venn diagram.

Answer (score 0):

$P(\text{no coffee}) = 100 - 80 = 20\%$

$P(\text{biscotti and coffee}) = 25\%$

So, $P(\text{no biscotti and coffee}) = 80 - 25 = 55\%$

$P(\text{biscotti and no coffee}) = 40 - 25 = 15\%$

$$P(\text{ biscotti given no coffee } ) = \frac{P(\text{ biscotti and no coffee) }}{P(\text{  no coffee)}} = \frac{15}{20} $$